# Trying to change the value of a property at runtime using reflection results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class that I'm writing unit tests for:

```
import java.io.File;

public class MyLogger {

    private final File logFile = new File("default");

    public File getLogFile() {
        return this.logFile;
    }
}
```

I would like to change the value assigned to `logFile` from within another class, e.g:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, Exception {

        MyLogger logger = new MyLogger();
        System.out.println(logger.getLogFile());

        setFinal(MyLogger.class.getDeclaredField("logFile"), new File("changed"));
        System.out.println(logger.getLogFile());
    }

    private static void setFinal(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        field.set(null, newValue);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the output/exception below:

```
default
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at Main.setFinal(Main.java:23)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Field.set` method in the wrong way. You need to supply the ***object*** on which the new field value has to be set, in your code it should be the `logger` object but you are passing `null`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, Exception {

    MyLogger logger = new MyLogger();
    System.out.println(logger.getLogFile());

    setFinal(logger, MyLogger.class.getDeclaredField("logFile"), new File("changed"));
    System.out.println(logger.getLogFile());
}

private static void setFinal(MyLogger logger, Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
    field.setAccessible(true);

    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    field.set(logger, newValue);
}
```

This is as per the method signature of `Field.set` from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)):

> Sets the field represented by this Field object on the specified
>   object argument to the specified new value.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do it like this using java.lang.reflect.Method check the below code whether it helps to fix your issue.

```
Method method = MyLogger.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getLogFile");
            method.setAccessible(true);
```

in getDeclaredMethod you need to give full method name.